Developer Settings Intent Not Working on Samsung Devices with Android 14
In my Android app, I have a button that triggers an intent to open the Developer Options screen (Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS). This button only appears when the user has already enabled Developer Options.
This functionality was working fine across various devices and Android versions. However, I recently encountered an issue on multiple Samsung devices running Android 14. When the button is clicked, instead of opening the Developer Options screen, a toast message appears stating "Turn on Developer options first," even though Developer Options are already enabled on the device.
Is this a known issue on Samsung devices with Android 14? Is there a known workaround or a different approach for launching the Developer Options screen on these devices?

There's no programming question here, and this is off-topic. Also, note that App Store questions are off-topic here - see Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?
